# How to mount PostgreSQL data directory in Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using minikube to run kubernetes locally. My local k8s have two pods which one of them is PostgreSQL and another one is my own app. I've mounted a `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` in order to make a stateful pod for PostgreSQL:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/psql"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Here is PostgreSQL deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        image: postgres:9.6
        ports:
        - name: postgres
          containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          name: postgres-persistent-storage
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

The problem is that PostgreSQL service doesn't start and this error occurs when I run its pod:

```
Error: /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main is not accessible; please fix the directory permissions (/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/ should be world readable)
No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ... (warning).
```

I've checked inside of PostgreSQL pod and I found that `/var/lib/postgresql` is empty, just like `/data/psql` In minikube host.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried shelling into the minikube Node and checking that the dir exists with the right permissions like in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/ ?

Comment: Are you running minikube in virtualbox?

Comment: @NicolaBen Yes, I'm using VirtualBox driver.

Comment: @RyanDawson What do you mean by right permission?

Comment: I'd give it full read-write for all users - chmod 777

Comment: @RyanDawson Yes, I gave full permission to all users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
```

to

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

With the wrong mountPoint postgres executables were overridden.

I attach an image with the data I see from inside the pod (on the left) and from inside minikube space (on the right, the little shell from virtualbox).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the postgres is now working but there's nothing in /var/lib/postgresql/data.

Comment: I'm using my own PostgreSQL image, does it make problem?

Comment: I used your files with the only correction I wrote on mountpoint. It's working for me. Try with the postgres official image.